# What IDEs have support for the Hack Language?

Tags: ide, editor, hacklang

Has anyone managed to find an IDE for Hack Language used on HHVM ?Is there any plugin available for the well-known IDEs like Eclipse,Netbeans,etc?
Thank you!

**Edit** : By the time SiebelsTim has embedded typechecker and made a basic syntax highlighting for Sublime. You can find the plugin [here](https://github.com/SiebelsTim/hack-sublime)

Comment: I also wish Netbeans would add support so that I can try it out. The only thing I've seen is the web-based [codebox](https://www.codebox.io/stack/hhvm)

Comment: @charmeleon Yes i have also seen that.It is not a good IDE. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the plugins for [vim](https://github.com/hhvm/vim-hack), [emacs](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/tree/master/hphp/hack/editor-plugins/emacs) and [Sublime](https://github.com/SiebelsTim/hack-sublime) <sup>1</sup>.

More support in other IDEs will be probably added in the future. I'm especially waiting for plugins for PHPStorm and Netbeans.

<sup>1</sup> = I don't use these editors, so please don't ask me how to install the plugins.

**EDIT**: There is now a page in HHVM docs with links to [various plugins](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/typechecker/editors).

Comment: Yeah me too.I am not a vim/emac enthusiast and the plugins i have installed are not as good as a modern IDE.As it seems we just have to wait...

Comment: If you'd like to contribute a plugin for your favorite editor, we'd love to have more! Most engineers at Facebook use vim, emacs, or FBIDE (esimated to be released late this summer) so we just haven't written them ourselves, but if others want to we'd love to take the pull request and/or link to them. I also hear JetBrains is working on something for PHPStorm, but don't know any details.

Comment: @JoshWatzman Sounds like a great idea for a weekend project; that is of course if it's not too complicated to do something like this. Do you guys have some sort of page for this where people can see which IDE plugins are currently in the process of being developed (and maybe join that team) ? If not, I think that would be a good idea...

Comment: I'm not aware of any such list if there is one, sorry. Maybe let us know in #hhvm on Freenode if you get started -- the channel is fairly active, there may be others interested there with whom you'd want to coordinate?

Comment: @JoshWatzman Do you have any news about the IDE ? I have read that there is an "unexpected delay"-as August has passed- but the lack of IDE has really slow down production. PHPStorm or Netbeans do not seem to set a 'high-priority' on Hack integration.

Comment: I don't have any more information than anyone else does on PHPStorm, NetBeans, or any other third-party IDE, unfortunately. I'm as excited as anyone else for Hack integration into those IDEs, and am willing to continue lending advice (and have actually already briefly chatted with a few of their folks), but don't have any knowledge or control over their prioritization process. Sorry!

Comment: @JoshWatzman I was actually speaking about the facebook-web ide, that we saw on the Hack presentation :) Thanks Josh for the infos !

Comment: Ah! Sorry, no new info on that one either. I don't work directly on it so I don't have great info, but last time I asked them (a week or to ago), their answer was basically that they were still working on it and it was taking longer than expected (which we should have expected ;)). We'll make sure to make a wide, loud announcement when it's ready!

Comment: The plugin for PHPStorm is absolutely necessary!

Comment: The link for the Sublime Text plugin is broken. Fix this, please!

Answer (score 6):

I've created a plugin for [Github's Atom Editor](http://atom.io), it can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/steelbrain/atom-hack).

It allows you to configure remote SSH Machines too (a great feature if you're on windows and running HHVM in a VirtualMachine).

Answer (score 2):

for netbeans integration there is already an issue opened
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243133

Comment: php storm 9 EAP is out http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/. among others there is a promising line Hack language support. but there is no guarantee whatsoever that it will make it to version 9.

Comment: PhpStorm support for Hack is postponed: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/06/hack-language-support-in-phpstorm-postponed/