# PHPStorm for Hack Language

Tags: ide, phpstorm, hacklang

I am kinda of a new user here and don't have enough reputation points to comment/ask on this question: [IDE support for Hack Lang.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582444/what-ides-have-support-for-the-hack-language)

So, I am hoping that since the last entry provided by Themis Beris someone has been able to get PHPStorm working properly with Hack.  I followed the 3 steps described in the post I mentioned, but still get compile-time errors on the classes I've written using Hack.  `<?hh` is not recognized, for instance.

Any suggestions as to how to get PHPStorm playing nice with Hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what Themis Beris is talking about on the linked question. (He seems to be saying something about PHPUnit, which is a completely separate issue.)

JetBrains has a [feature request open for Hack support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21737) and last I heard was very actively working on it. But as of this writing (Feb 2015) it's not released yet.

Comment: huh... Thanks for clarifying this Josh.  I guess it is back to vi and emacs for a while :/

Comment: @Gabriel you would want to add SublimeText to the list which seems to be more convenient :-)